# Replace the following if conditions in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to replace the following SQL query in SQLite but seems like I don't have much options available to write this query completely in SQLite. I am aware of using the where not exists of SQLite but not sure how to use the same when there are nested if conditions after if not exists condition like below. I can take care of this issue in code behind but wanted to know if this can be taken care off completely in a SQLite query.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id= @someId)
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        IF @someparam=@otherparam
            SELECT col1,col2 from tb1
            where tb1.somecolumn='xyz' or tb1.someothercolumn='pqr' 
            order by case col1 
                WHEN 'something' THEN 1
                WHEN 'someother' THEN 2
                END

        IF @someparam=@otherparam2 OR @someparam = 'xyz'
            SELECT col1,col2 from tb1
            where tb1.somecolumn='abc' or tb1.someothercolumn='def' 
            order by case col1 
               WHEN 'something' THEN 2
                WHEN 'someother' THEN 1
                END
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        IF @someparam2=@otherparam3
SELECT col1,col2 from (select distinct col1, col2 from tb3, tb1 where somecolumn not in 
(select acolumn from tb1 where ggg = hhh) and tb1.somecolumn = 'zzz') as wwww
            order by case col1
               WHEN 'nnn' THEN 1
               WHEN 'mmm' THEN 2
               WHEN 'kkk' THEN 3
                END 

        IF @someparam2=@otherparam4 OR @someparam = 'xyz'
            SELECT col1,col2 from tb1
            where tb1.somecolumn='ccc' or tb1.someothercolumn='ddd'
            order by case col1
               WHEN 'nnn' THEN 2
               WHEN 'mmm' THEN 3
               WHEN 'kkk' THEN 1
                END 
    END
END
```

Comment: All four of the selects are the same. Though in general, SQLite doesn't provide procedural operations like this; you'd have to do it in your application code.

Comment: I think you can use one query by using `CASE` , but when all your queries are same it is not needed here - And also if `@otherparam` equals to `@otherparam2` you will have two results!? - please edit your question ;).

Comment: @shA.t perhaps I should have been much more specific in my question. In my actual query all those select statements are not same even though they select col1, col2 the where conditions differ in each select statement which are hard coded sometimes. I will try to edit this.

Answer (score 0):

When you have same columns in your final query you can `UNION` your queries and then filter your expected result like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM tb1
WHERE 
    1 = CASE 
        WHEN (NOT EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             (@someparam = @otherparam) AND
             (tb1.somecolumn='xyz' or tb1.someothercolumn='pqr') THEN 1
        WHEN (NOT EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             (@someparam = @otherparam2 OR @someparam = 'xyz') AND
             (tb1.somecolumn='abc' or tb1.someothercolumn='def') THEN 1
        WHEN (EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             (@someparam2 = @otherparam3) AND
             (tb1.somecolumn='aaa' or tb1.someothercolumn='bbb') THEN 1
        WHEN (EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             (@someparam2 = @otherparam4 OR @someparam = 'xyz') AND
             (tb1.somecolumn='ccc' or tb1.someothercolumn='ddd') THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN (NOT EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             (@someparam = @otherparam AND col1 = 'something') THEN 1
        WHEN (NOT EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             (@someparam = @otherparam AND col1 = 'someother') THEN 2

        WHEN (NOT EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             (@someparam = @otherparam2 OR @someparam = 'xyz') AND
             (col1 = 'something') THEN 2
        WHEN (NOT EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             (@someparam = @otherparam2 OR @someparam = 'xyz') AND
             (col1 = 'someother') THEN 1

        WHEN (EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             (@someparam2 = @otherparam3) AND
             (col1 = 'nnn') THEN 1
        WHEN (EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             (@someparam2 = @otherparam3) AND
             (col1 = 'mmm') THEN 2
        WHEN (EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             (@someparam2 = @otherparam3) AND
             (col1 = 'kkk') THEN 3

        WHEN (EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             (@someparam2 = @otherparam4 OR @someparam = 'xyz') AND
             (col1 = 'nnn') THEN 2
        WHEN (EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             (@someparam2 = @otherparam4 OR @someparam = 'xyz') AND
             (col1 = 'mmm') THEN 3
        WHEN (EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             (@someparam2 = @otherparam4 OR @someparam = 'xyz') AND
             (col1 = 'kkk') THEN 1

        ELSE 10
    END
```

---

or you can mix your `ORDER BY` like this:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN ((NOT EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             ((@someparam = @otherparam AND col1 = 'something') OR
             ((@someparam = @otherparam2 OR @someparam = 'xyz') AND (col1 = 'someother'))) OR
             ((EXISTS(SELECT col1 from tb1 where tbl.id=@someId)) AND 
             ((@someparam2 = @otherparam3 AND col1 = 'nnn') OR
             ((@someparam2 = @otherparam4 OR @someparam = 'xyz') AND (col1 = 'kkk'))) THEN 1
         ...
```

Comment: Order by is invalid before union all as it should come after union all. I edited my question to include the order by clauses with case statements in the original query.

Comment: i have other issues now with the above query, my original query has one select statement which is different and which includes two tables. I edited my question to reflect the same.

Comment: Update: Made some more changes and made the query work, but it's very slow. I decided to take a different approach at this point. Thanks for the hlep.